# Running Razor pages site in Elastic Beanstalk vs serverless Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, razor-pages

I have a Razor pages site, and its been running nice in Elastic Beanstalk, however, today, i found out, i could also host a razor pages site as serverless in AWS Lambda?? (Which i have only been using for WebApi's)

It all seems to work... only difference i have spotted, is with elastic beanstalk, its easier to deploy to different environments (dev, stag, test, prod)

Can anyone point out the differences regarding to razor pages on Elastic Beanstalk vs AWS Lambda?  I have read about differences with WebApi's, but nothing on an actual website

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, been using lambda for my razor pages site, and just works the same, only difference, is with Lambda after a while your site can go to sleep (something like that), and it will be a little bit slow... there are ways around that, like having another lambda call something on your razor site to keep it awake.  But for me, this is fine at the moment

Other than that, instead of paying for EC2 for the ElasticBeanstalk site, im not actually paying anything now (probably only small amounts when the site is used a bit more)

Havent worked out the best way for different environments, but that will be another question